# Get row number of datatable in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

At times, I may require to show the row no as a column in GUI, say SerialNo# kind of stuff.

```
Expected:
------+------
  #   + Value
------+------
  1   + 20
------+-----
  2   + 30
------+------
```

Sample Code:

```
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<>(""), "placeholder") {
        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item cellItem, String componentId, IModel model) {
            int cellIndex = cellItem.getIndex();
            int rowIndex = ????
            item.add(new Label(componentId, new Model<>(rowIndex)));
        }
    });
```

What is the best way to get rowIndex from there?

Answer (score 2):

The cell is contained in a Row, through a rowItem. This is also an `Item` and higher in the component-tree. You can find it using the `findParent` method.

```
columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<>(""), "placeholder") {
            @Override
            public void populateItem(Item cellItem, String componentId, IModel model) {
                    Item rowItem = item.findParent( Item.class );
                    int rowIndex = rowItem.getIndex();
            }
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't help. in my case item.findParent( Item.class ) was null :(